# FileNotFound Exception While Opening File

Tags: c#, resources, streamreader

I have a project that reads several text files into a List via StreamReader, I have the files added to my solution under Resources, when I try to reference the file using StreamReader, I get a "FileNotFound" exception.

The files are being copied over to bin\debug\Resources, and the error says it's trying to locate them under bin\debug.. How do I reference them without using the literal path? (e.g. C:\users\etc) since when I compile it won't run on another person's PC if I reference actual path.

Code that calls text file:

```
using (sr = new StreamReader("FileName.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        Names.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

Under the text files properties I have it set to "Copy Always" and under Build Action it's set to "Embedded Resource".

Basically my main goal is to compile the project into an exe with the text files being referenced internally (their contents aren't changed by the program), so my application will be portable.

Comment: Have you tried "Resources/Filename.txt"? :)

Comment: try to copy the file under bin\debug

Comment: Use a relative file path.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @J0HN, this is working now, thanks. Am trying to make it portable now with Shaharyar's answer. Tianyun Ling, do you mean manually, or how do I do this in Visual Studio? tnw I really don't want to do that, see question. John Saunders, okay will read that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is clear. Change code to:

```
using (sr = new StreamReader("Resources\FileName.txt"))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        Names.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, the error will be removed by just replacing the path `Resources\FileName.txt`

In other case, as you mentioned that you want to make a portable .exe. Then you need to embed files in your application. Now see how to embed files in your .exe :

- Expand `Properties` in `Solution Explorer`
- Double click on `Resources`

  On left top of `Resources` tab, there will be a combo box
  [image]
- Choose Files
- Now just drag and drop your files there
- To embed files, you can go to properties of every file by right
  clicking on it. Choose `Embedded in .resx` from `Persistence`
  property.

To use the file you can use `Properties.Resources.YourFile`.

For more details, follow the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: (Sorry, thunderstorm caused electricity to go out at my house, back on for now) Your answer is incredibly clear, but where is the option to set "Embedded in .Resx" ? i.imgur.com/amQpvUC.png

Comment: Yes, this option is not available for `Files`, but it works in same way as other embedded files do. I never researched it why, shame on me !!